# How to add info to rails JSON object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Object ChatMessage, and I need a JSON with its User. I am using:

```
chat_message.as_json(include: { author: { only: [:id, :phone_number, 
:country_alpha_2]})
```

I want to add data to author, let's say `hello: "world"`. How can I do this?

I tried something like:

```
.as_json(include: { author: { only: [:id, :phone_number, 
:country_alpha_2], hello: 'world'}})
```

and

```
.as_json(include: { author: { only: [:id, :phone_number, 
:country_alpha_2]}.merge(hello: 'world') })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
.as_json(include: { author: { only: [:id, :phone_number, :country_alpha_2] } })
.tap { |json| json['author']['hello'] = 'world' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to tinker with the final hash yourself, i.e.

```
json = chat_message.as_json(include: { author: { only: [:id, :phone_number, :country_alpha_2] }})
json["author"].merge!(hello: "world")
```

you might add a method to your `User` model and use `:methods` as described in [as_json](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) docs:

```
class User
  def hello
    "world"
  end
end

chat_message.as_json(include: {
  author: { only: [:id, :phone_number, :country_alpha_2], methods: :hello }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought of using this solution too, but I did not use it as it would only be used in that hash. Sebastian Palma's solution was what I was looking for.